# IOS Extract Output Image from Masked Image

Tags: ios, image-processing, swift3, mask

I have created an image mask based on user input, and the result includes both foreground and the created mask (mixed).

[Masked Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/342qI.jpg)

I am trying to find a way to return only the masked image, and have been unsuccessful identifying a way to change the alpha value of the mask.  Can anyone help? I want to get to a final image of the selected area.

The code I am working with to create the mask and return the masked image is here: [Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybGPX.png)

Answer (score 0):

After continuous research and testing, I used the `getForeground:andMask` method to separate the target into two sets of values. Then, I inverted the mask and added the resulting image and inverted mask to a `SubView` with a clear background color.